# Seaborn: how to set min and max of the x-axis in a heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn

this is the code to build my colormap

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.set(font_scale=5.0, rc={'text.usetex' : True})
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(10.5,9.)})
font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 22}

matplotlib.rc('font', **font)

colormap = pd.read_csv('m_colormap_5.csv')
print(colormap.info())

colormapBetaAlpha = colormap[['dihedral', 'scaled_momentum', 'mBetaAlpha']].pivot(index = 'dihedral', columns = 'scaled_momentum', values = 'mBetaAlpha')
colormapBetaAlpha.to_csv('pivot_table_beta_alpha.csv')
g = sns.heatmap(colormapBetaAlpha, xticklabels = 20, yticklabels= 20, cbar_kws={'label': r'$\log(m/$ps$^{-2})$'})
xlabels = ['{:,.2f}'.format(float(x.get_text())) for x in g.get_xticklabels()]
xlabels = ["$" + x + "$" for x in xlabels]


ylabels = ['{:,.2f}'.format(float(x.get_text())) for x in g.get_yticklabels()]
ylabels = ["$" + x + "$" for x in ylabels]
# Setting the font on the colorbar label
g.figure.axes[-1].yaxis.label.set_size(14)

# Setting the font on the colormap ticks
cmap_labels = [x.get_text() for x in g.figure.axes[-1].get_yticklabels()]
g.figure.axes[-1].set_yticklabels(cmap_labels, fontsize = 14)
g.set_xticklabels(xlabels, fontsize = 14)
g.set_yticklabels(ylabels, fontsize = 14)
plt.xlabel(r'$p_{\varphi}/ \sqrt{k_B T g^\prime}$', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel(r"$\varphi$", fontsize = 14)
plt.savefig("mDownToUp_height_5.png")
plt.show()
```

The result is nice [image] but I would like the x axis range from -10.0 to 10.0. I have tried many things from matplotlib, like "plt.xlim(-10.0, 10.0)" but it does not work properly. Also I have tried to write down an hard coded list to pass to the xlabel, but the result is quite ugly. How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work properly"?

Comment: It deeply alters the graph. I cannot insert a graph in a comment, therefore I cannot be clearer .

Comment: You should [edit] your question with new relevant details that people ask for in the comments. This way, new readers of the question will get the full picture without having to read all the comments. You can always mention the commenter to tell them you've edited your question so they can look at your updates in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `xticklabels = 21`?

-10 to 10 with 0 in the middle adds to 21 ticks.

I am assuming your data goes to +10 as it seems to from the plot. Uploading the input file with the data would help.

Answer (score -1):

For example, if the code

plt.ylim(-10, 10) 
is used the map is deeply alter as reported [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zusLA.png